# Firebase paginating data returns same data?

Tags: swift, firebase, pagination, tableview

Currently, I am initially loading the user's messages through :

```swift
  func fetchMessages() {

    if started == true {

    let messageRef = Database.database().reference().child("messages").queryOrdered(byChild: "convoID").queryEqual(toValue: convoID).queryLimited(toLast: 10)
    messageRef.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        if let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
            let newMessage = message()
            newMessage.messageText =  value["content"] as? String
            newMessage.sender = value["sender"] as? String
            newMessage.messageID = snapshot.key
            self.messageList.append(newMessage)


            self.queryingStatus = true
            self.messagesTableView.reloadData()
            self.scrollToBottom()
        }

    }
}
}
```

Now, to minimize the data download, I decided to break the messages into chunks as such so that the user will download ten subsequent messages each time they pull up on the table view:

```swift
   @objc func handleRefresh(_ refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {

    let lastIDDictionary = messageList[0]
    let lastIDQueried = lastIDDictionary.messageID

    let messageRefAddition = Database.database().reference().child("messages").queryOrdered(byChild: "convoID").queryLimited(toLast: 10).queryEnding(atValue: convoID, childKey: lastIDQueried!)
    messageRefAddition.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

            if let messageValue = child.value as? NSDictionary {

            let newMessage = message()
            newMessage.messageText =  messageValue["content"] as? String
            newMessage.sender = messageValue["sender"] as? String
            newMessage.messageID = child.key

            self.messageList.insert(newMessage, at: 0)
            self.messagesTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

    }


    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

The problem is, when I pull up on the table view, the first time it returns some new messages (I am not sure whether the order is even correct). However, when I pull on the table view again to refresh, it adds those same ten messages again. I printed the `lastIDQueried` in the refresh method, and after the initial load the ID remains the same even though I am accessing the first item in the array of dictionaries? Basically,when I refresh the table view, it is not querying the correct data and my pagination implementation does not seem to be working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the problem was that I was inserting the post in the wrong place in the array and the last item was still being added to the array which was always the same (as I ended on the value). As such, I added a counter that incremented each time a value was added. Then, I inserted the subsequent post at the counter value in the array then again incremented. Finally, if the message ID was equal to the current first message in array, I would not insert it.